# LINQ IEnumerable<T> Memory Structure

Tags: c#, linq, memory

So I understand that the most common collections in `C#` all implement the `IEnumerable<T>` interface: `List<T>`, `T[]` and `Dictionary<TKey,TVal>` all do this.

However, when you run a LINQ query such as:

`myCol.Where(myBoolMethod);`

You are returned data as an unknown type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`.

Consequently, I'm wondering how this data is actually stored until you convert it into a more useful format through `.ToList()`, `.ToArray()` etc.

Does it remain in the type of the source? Does it get stored in a pseudo-array? Is it some sort of combination of the above?

Further to this, is there any reason why converting to one type of `IEnumerable<T>` will ALWAYS be quicker than converting to a different one from - ie where `myCol.Where(myBoolMethod).ToArray()` is always quicker than `myCol.Where(myBoolMethod).ToList()` regardless of the data types involved?

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *stored*. It represents the ability to *obtain* the data at a later point in time, but the data itself is still lurking in the original collection(s) from which the linq query has been composed. (And any logic that exists to create new values from expressions)

This is why there are all kinds of admonitions against storing these results without using a `ToXxx` method if there's any possibility that you'll actually cause the query to execute multiple times.

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot more sense, thank you. Unless a better answer materialises I'll accept this one once the time limit has passed.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it remain in the type of the source? Does it get stored in a pseudo-array? Is it some sort of combination of the above?

Most LINQ extension methods will loop over the source every time you *access* the resulting `IEnumerable<T>` (it's called deferred execution). The results are generally not stored in an intermediate source.

> is there any reason why converting to one type of IEnumerable will ALWAYS be quicker than converting to a different one from

Yes, calling `ToArray` or `ToList` will *execute* the enumerable and materialize it. If you don't use the returned `IEnumerable<T>`, it will not materialize it. The performance impact is about 0.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually `WhereEnumerableIterator` (if myCol is `IEnumerable`).
http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,119

It contains just reference to initial `myCol` and reference to `Func<T, bool>`.

If `mycol` is another type, it could be another, more optimized LINQ iterator.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `myCol.Where(myBoolMethod)` the data is actually not being enumerated. It is not stored in array or whatever else, you just get the **enumerator** which lets you enumerate this collection.

When you do `.ToArray()` it actually uses enumerator to create a new array.